# Garbage collection (GC) in Android PlayN

Tags: playn

In Chris Pruett's talk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk
writing real time games for android, he meticulously avoided the GC from running by never losing a reference or creating a new allocation until a time of his choosing.

Should that design pattern be used in playN in general? I'd assume it's not possible if the library itself does not try to avoid allocation in the general case (memory pooling). I.e. if you receive new Touch.Events when implementing a Touch.Listener, if these and other objects aren't being constantly recycled, then attempts to use the API this way would be for naught... OR perhaps PlayN is close to being no-GC compliant and then it's still worth the developer putting in this effort.

Thanx :-)

Update: I posted the wrong Chris Pruett talk. Watch the bit here where he talks about the GC. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=U4Bk5rmIpic#t=1748s

Comment: Looking at the example I mentioned, new Touch.Events are definitely created constantly throughout user interaction on Android, so I would imagine this has not entered into the design philosophy of the PlayN team. Maybe it's still worth coding using memory pools, in case one day the underlying libraries change? :-/

Comment: perhaps GC isn't as big a problem as its made out to be - i would imagine the bottleneck to be the rendering...

Comment: See the link I posted. Chris says that the GC can pause for as long as 100-300ms ... that's a pretty bad bottleneck. Arguably this was 2009, but do you know of specific improvements? I guess hardware is a lot better today.

Answer (score 1):

Most of Android devices have multi-core CPU now. It's not a real problem anymore I think.

However, you can check traces from GC in your device logcat. On my 3 years mono-core device, it's less than 5 ms when running my game.

If you're worry about memory management on Android, I recommend you this video: [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Comment: 5ms is pretty good. On my current stack (not playN), I get ~15-30ms GCs.